# When using shared_ptr should I just use the shared_ptr declaration once or declare shared_ptr everywhere I pass it?

Tags: c++

When using `shared_ptr`, should I just use the `shared_ptr` declaration once or declare `shared_ptr` everywhere I pass it?

So in the function where I new up the instance I wrap it in a `shared_ptr` but when I return it from the function I could also return a `shared_ptr` or, using the `get()` on the `shared_ptr`, just return a normal pointer.

So my question is, should I just use `shared_ptr<myType>` when I new the instance and then pass normal pointers around or should I be passing `shared_ptr<myType>` everywhere?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Creating a `shared_ptr` doesn't imbue magical powers on its pointee object. The magic is all in the `shared_ptr` — and its copies — itself. If you stop using it, you lose your reference counting; worse, because you used it *at some point*, the object will be automatically deleted when you don't expect it.

The *whole point* of having `shared_ptr` is that you know your object won't get destroyed when you're still using it somewhere.

In the following:

```
T* foo() {
   shared_ptr<T> sp(new T());
   return sp.get();
   // ^ the only shared_ptr<T> referencing the obj is dead;
   // obj is deleted;
   // returned pointer invalid before you can even do anything with it
}
```

your pointer is immediately invalid.

There may well be circumstances in which you extract a raw pointer, but these should be rare. If you are in a function where you *know* you don't need the reference counting, then just pass the `shared_ptr` in by reference.